# Delete lines or rows in a tab-delimited file, by number of cells in that lines or rows

Tags: awk, sed, row

I want to delete lines/rows which have less then or equal to 5 columns or more than 7 colunms in txt file delimited with tab. This means I want to keep lines with just 6 columns in a tab-delimited files.

I prefer to `sed` and `awk` to do this job.

Comment: Added sed/awk to attract the right attention

Comment: [@kurumi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595516/delete-lines-or-rows-in-a-tab-delimited-file-by-number-of-cells-in-that-lines-or/5595663#5595663) looks like it will do the job. If it does not, you may wish to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
  awk -F"\t" 'NF==6' file >temp && mv temp file
```

Answer (score 1):

on command line :

```
awk '!(NF>=7 && NF<=5)' file
```

Comment: By default tab is the delimiter if not specified any

Comment: ah, I thought it was generic whitespace. I remove my downvote