# Deleting rows that have more than a certain number of columns in a comma delimited file

Tags: r

I have rows/observations in a comma delimited file that ideally should have 55 columns. But there are fields such as addresses that have an an extra comma within them. Such as **Manhattan, New York** should be one field **Manhattan, New York** but I get two fields **Manhattan** and **New York** when I read the file which increases the number of columns.

Is there anyway I can delete such observations using R or any tool such as Delimit or Excel?

I would eventually like to load this file into R for analysis.

I agree my question is similar to [Delete lines or rows in a tab-delimited file, by number of cells in that lines or rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595516/delete-lines-or-rows-in-a-tab-delimited-file-by-number-of-cells-in-that-lines-o) but I am looking for a solution in R.

**Input**

```
Name, Address, DOB
John, Manhattan, New York, 2/8/1990
Jacob, Arizona, 9/10/2012
Smith, New Jersey, 8/10/2016
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name, Address, DOB
Jacob, Arizona, 9/10/2012
Smith, New Jersey, 8/10/2016
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example dataset and expected output

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind with your comma separated file is that you have comma's in the data without quoting the data in each column as in `"John","Manhattan, New York","2/8/1990"`.  If you have control over how the input file is created, you could quote the data like is often done with csv files.  Alternatively you would work with tab separated files when you have commas in your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I do not advocate doing what you want to do, which is to throw away records. Nonetheless, if this is what you want to do, you could do so as follows.

Assuming your data is stored as a text in a file called `foo`, you can use the `count.fields` function to count fields defined by the presence of `sep`. Then just omit them from the `readLines` function.

```
text <-
"Name, Address, DOB
John, Manhattan, New York, 2/8/1990
Jacob, Arizona, 9/10/2012
Smith, New Jersey, 8/10/2016
"
cat(text, file = "foo", sep = ",")
fields <- count.fields("foo", sep = ",")
readLines("foo")[fields == 3]
```

Comment: what would you advocate doing in such a scenario? Is there a way to include the correct address values under the address column? And I figured how to convert it to a dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: In this simple example would extract all the words between the first word and the first number and paste them together.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to read with `readLines` and then create a quote around the words with `sub`, and then read the dataset with `read.table`

```
lines1 <- gsub(",", " ", lines)
lines1[-1] <- sub("^(\\S+)\\s+([^0-9]+\\b)\\s+(\\d+.*)", "\\1 '\\2' \\3", 
                              lines1[-1])

read.table(text=lines1,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)
#   Name             Address       DOB
#1  John Manhattan  New York  2/8/1990
#2 Jacob             Arizona 9/10/2012
#3 Smith          New Jersey 8/10/2016
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
```

Comment: Any chance you would decompose your regex into `package:rex` terms?

Comment: @rpierce I have never used the package rex, so not sure about how that works.

Answer (score 2):

We can count the number of commas in each line and subset the line vector for only those lines that have the expected number of commas:

```
## read in raw file lines using readLines()
lines1 <- readLines(textConnection('Name, Address, DOB\nJohn, Manhattan, New York, 2/8/1990\nJacob, Arizona, 9/10/2012\nSmith, New Jersey, 8/10/2016\n'));

## subset for lines with the expected number of commas
lines2 <- lines1[2L==sapply(lines1,function(s) nchar(s)-nchar(gsub(',','',s)))];

## result
lines1;
## [1] "Name, Address, DOB"
## [2] "John, Manhattan, New York, 2/8/1990"
## [3] "Jacob, Arizona, 9/10/2012"
## [4] "Smith, New Jersey, 8/10/2016"
## [5] ""
lines2;
## [1] "Name, Address, DOB"
## [2] "Jacob, Arizona, 9/10/2012"
## [3] "Smith, New Jersey, 8/10/2016"
```

Comment: I did not see this when I clicked submit. This is a clever solution without knowing the `count.fields` function.

Comment: I didn't even know about the `count.fields()` function! Very useful, +1 to you